# Netty: How to handle received chunks from a ChunkedFile

Tags: netty, file-transfer, chunks

I am new to netty and I am attempting to transfer a chunkedfile from a server to a client. Sending the chunks work just fine. The problem is on how to handle the received chunks and write them to a file. Both methods that I tried give me a direct buffer error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {

         System.out.println(in.toString());


         //METHOD 1: write to file
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test.txt");
         fos.write(in.array());


         //METHOD 2: getting desperate   
         //InputStream inputStream = new ByteBufInputStream(in); 
         //ChunkedStream chkStream = new ChunkedStream(inputStream);             
         //outputStream.write( (chkStream.readChunk(ctx).readBytes(in, 0)).array());

         //if(chkStream.isEndOfInput()){
         //  outputStream.close();
         //  inputStream.close();
         //  chkStream.close();
         //}


         return;

     }

     out.add(in.toString(charset));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a FileChannel:

```
ByteBuf in = ...;
ByteBuffer nioBuffer = in.nioBuffer();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test.txt");
FileChannel channel = fos.getChannel();
while (nioBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
    channel.write(nioBuffer);
}
channel.close();
fos.close();
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. That was pretty dumb of me!

Answer (score 2):

I use netty 4.1 version to receive chunks and write to file.

1. use **ByteBuf** to receive the ChunkFile or FileRegion and convert it to **ByteBuffer** which is java nio.
2. Get the **FileChannel** of RandomAccessFile and write ByteBuffer in.

Below is my **handler** code:

```
public class FileClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

@Override
protected void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
        throws Exception {

    File file = new File(dest);//remember to change dest

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    ByteBuf byteBuf = (ByteBuf) msg;
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = byteBuf.nioBuffer();
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();

    while (byteBuffer.hasRemaining()){;
        fileChannel.position(file.length());
        fileChannel.write(byteBuffer);
    }

    byteBuf.release();
    fileChannel.close();
    randomAccessFile.close();

}}
```

[netty](/questions/tagged/netty)