# Netty client not receiving the complete data sent by the Server

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I am designing a Netty based solution to transfer a file from Server to the Client over TCP. The client specifies the location of the file and then the server sends the file to the client.

Currently, the solution works fine for files with small size (< 2MB of data).

If the file to be sent is larger than ~5MB **only partial data** is sent and this varies (every time not the same amount of data is sent). Also, it is seen from the log that the Server has sent *the complete amount of data* (file).

The issue is the client is **not receiving complete data** sent by the server. What is wrong in my below code? or Can someone point me to right direction.

Below is my client, server and their handlers:
(For *brevity* I have listed only the methods that is of importance)

Client:

```
 public class FileClient {

        private final static int PORT = 8992;
        private final static String HOST = "127.0.0.1";

        public class ClientChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

            private SslContext sslContext = null;
            private String srcFile = "";
            private String destFile = "";

            public ClientChannelInitializer(String srcFile, String destFile, SslContext sslCtx) {
                this.sslContext = sslCtx;
                this.srcFile = srcFile;
                this.destFile = destFile;
            }

            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
                pipeline.addLast(sslContext.newHandler(socketChannel.alloc(), HOST, PORT));
                pipeline.addLast("clientHandler", new FileClientHandler(srcFile, destFile));
            }

        }

        private void startUp(String srcFile, String destFile) throws Exception {
            SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();
            EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

                Bootstrap clientBootstrap = new Bootstrap();
                clientBootstrap.group(workerGroup);
                clientBootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
                clientBootstrap.option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
                clientBootstrap.handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
                clientBootstrap.handler(new ClientChannelInitializer(srcFile, destFile, sslCtx));

Channel channel = clientBootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT)).sync().channel();
                channel.closeFuture().sync();
            } 
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            String src = "/Users/home/src/test.mp4";
            String dest = "/Users/home/dest/test.mp4";
            new FileClient().startUp(src, dest);
        }

    }
```

ClientHandler:

```
public class FileClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {


    private final String sourceFileName;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private Path destFilePath;
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[0];



    public FileClientHandler(String SrcFileName, String destFileName) {
        this.sourceFileName = SrcFileName;
        this.destFilePath = Paths.get(destFileName);
        System.out.println("DestFilePath-" + destFilePath);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(ToByteBuff(this.sourceFileName));
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf byteBuff) throws Exception {
        if (this.outputStream == null) {
            Files.createDirectories(this.destFilePath.getParent());
            if (Files.exists(this.destFilePath)) {
                Files.delete(this.destFilePath);
            }
            this.outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(this.destFilePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                    StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }

        int size = byteBuff.readableBytes();
        if (size > this.buffer.length) {
            this.buffer = new byte[size];
        }
        byteBuff.readBytes(this.buffer, 0, size);
        this.outputStream.write(this.buffer, 0, size);

    }
```

FileServer:

```
public class FileServer {
    private final int PORT = 8992;

    public void run() throws Exception {
        SelfSignedCertificate ssc = new SelfSignedCertificate();
        final SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(ssc.certificate(), ssc.privateKey()).build();
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)).childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                            pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));

                            pipeline.addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());
                            pipeline.addLast(new FilServerFileHandler());
                        }
                    });
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(PORT).sync();

            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new FileServer().run();
    }
}
```

FileServerHandler:

```
public class FilServerFileHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buff) throws Exception {
        String filePathStr = byteBuf.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

        File file = new File(filePathStr);
        RandomAccessFile raf = null;
        ChannelFuture sendFileFuture;
        try {
            raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

            sendFileFuture = ctx.writeAndFlush(new ChunkedNioFile(raf.getChannel()),
                    ctx.newProgressivePromise());

            sendFileFuture.addListener(new ChannelProgressiveFutureListener() {
                public void operationComplete(ChannelProgressiveFuture future) throws Exception {
                    System.err.println("Transfer complete.");
                }

                public void operationProgressed(ChannelProgressiveFuture future, long progress, long total)
                        throws Exception {
                    if (total < 0) { // total unknown
                        System.err.println("Transfer progress: " + progress);
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Transfer progress: " + progress + " / " + total);
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        } finally {
            if (raf != null)
                raf.close();
        }
    }
```

I have checked [SO Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357672/sending-file-from-server-to-client-by-using-netty-io) and [SO Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888260/netty-how-to-handle-received-chunks-from-a-chunkedfile)

Comment: Why not use the method from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888260/netty-how-to-handle-received-chunks-from-a-chunkedfile to your client?

Comment: Thank you. I had checked this post as well. Even this doesn't work. Only upto 5MB of data is received/saved from whatever amount (> 5MB) of data being sent from the server.

Comment: try add an exceptionCaught method in your client and server handler and check if an exception was thrown during transport. And also, is your server behind any kind of proxy? like nginx or haproxy

Comment: @kelgon I do have the exceptionCaught method, only for brevity purpose I didn't mention it here. 1. Nope, there's no exception thrown during the transport. 2. Nope, there's no proxy involved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your problem by a little tweak in `FilServerFileHandler`:

```
public class FileServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buff) throws Exception {
        String filePathStr = buff.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

        File file = new File(filePathStr);
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        ChannelFuture sendFileFuture;
        try {
            sendFileFuture = ctx.writeAndFlush(new ChunkedNioFile(raf.getChannel()), ctx.newProgressivePromise());
            sendFileFuture.addListener(new ChannelProgressiveFutureListener() {
                public void operationComplete(ChannelProgressiveFuture future) throws Exception {
                    System.err.println("Transfer complete.");
                    if (raf != null) {
                        raf.close();
                    }
                }
                public void operationProgressed(ChannelProgressiveFuture future, long progress, long total)
                        throws Exception {
                    if (total < 0) { // total unknown
                        System.err.println("Transfer progress: " + progress);
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("Transfer progress: " + progress + " / " + total);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I moved `raf.close()` into `operationComplete` method.

The partial transportation is caused by the closing of `raf` during write operation. Note that `ctx.writeAndFlush` is an async call, so the `raf.close()` in `finally` block might be triggered before the write operation complete, especially when the size of the file is large enough.

Comment: btw, FileRegion is better in performance than ChunkedNioFile if your operating system supports zero-copy(i.e sendfile() in linux), which transfer bytes directly between file system and nic buffer, while ChunkedNioFile needs to read bytes into user space(JVM heap)

Comment: Okay. will incorporate that. I am not clear about one thing. Is it not required to use some kind of LengthBasedDecoders while transferring large files using TCP?

Comment: Yes, it is not required. Large data will be sent through TCP in small packets, fragmentation and assembly is performed in TCP layer. The `channelRead0` in client-side handler will be called multiple times.

Comment: And also I forgot to mention that zero-copy transfer the file data as is, so you cannot use ssl or any kind of data encryption technique

Comment: kelgon Thank you. ok got it. will use zero-copy only in the case of non-ssl.